# Repeated measures factorial ANOVA - independent variables from an equation

Tags: anova, variance, manova

I have responses from 30 patients for 4 independent variables. ind_var1 has 2 levels, ind_var2 has 3 levels, ind_var3 has 2 levels and ind_var4 has 4 levels. No groups in the dependent variable. So the matrix for independent variables is 2X3X2X4. Each patient is measured for all the combinations. So I chose the repeated measures factorial ANOVA design and post hoc tests by choosing preferred combinations of independent variables. But ind_var3 and ind_var4 are related through a mathematical equation. Does this violates using factorial ANOVA model. Also, I would like to whether my choice of test is appropriate according to the variable properties I described. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand: If you say: "ind_var3 and ind_var4 are related through a mathematical equation", does that mean that the choice of ind_var3 is determining the value of ind_var4 (or the other way around)? If so, how can you then accomplish that "Each patient is measured for all the combinations."?

Comment: Thank you for replying. its a measure of signal complexity. ind_var3 and ind_var4 are two inputs. As an example, when apply var3 = 3 and var4 = 2.0 and run the complexity analysis we get a complexity map of the brain. If we change the var3=2 and var4 = 3.0 we get a different complexity map of the brain. Goal is to run ANOVA to find the best parameters

Comment: IIUC, you are concerned about the mathematical equation that relates ind_var3 and ind_var4. What is this equation? Or: what is the difference between the relation between ind_var3 and ind_var4 and the relations between any other pair of independent variables?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am concerned about that. var1 indicate frequency manipulated time series of the brain image vs original time series. var2 is the TR (repetition time) of the image, its an image acquisition parameter. var3 and var4 parameters of the complexity measures.  C(m,r)=(number of x(j) such that d[x(i),x(j)] <= r)/(N-m+1). here m and r are var3 and var4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relations between the independent variables are not relevant for ANOVA. And the formula you gave in the comments looks like those two variables only appear in the same equation but don't determine each other's values. Thus this doesn't prevent you from going through all combinations. Thus, no, this doesn't violate any assumptions for factorial ANOVA.

And everything you describe seems coherent, so, based on the information given, the choice of your tests is appropriate. Just make sure that you provide for all the assumptions required by ANOVA and your post hoc test.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. This explanation is really helpful.